# Calling a function from inside async's callback inside an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
var async = require("async");

module.exports = function(vars){

    return {

        a: function(){
            console.log("a()");
        },

        b: function(){

            var self = this;

            async.series([
                function(callback){
                    ...
                    callback();
                },
                function(callback){
                    ...
                    callback();
                }
            ], function(){
                self.a(); // <------- err
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Then I'm calling b as:

```
var test = require("./test.js")({});
test.b();
```

but I'm getting this error: `Object #<Object> has no method 'a'`. Why?

Edit:

Sorry, this code actually runs fine, but I'm getting that error in my code in production.

The only difference from this example (which works correctly) and my code (which doesn't)
is that my demo code is called directly:

```
var test = require("./test.js")({});
test.b();
```

while my production code is called from another library:

```
var my_code = require("./something.js")({});
imap_notify.on_new_mail(my_code.my_func);
```

Comment: how is the method `b` called?

Comment: self = b in this example

Comment: Can you provide the output if you `console.log(self)` from within the anonymous function you're calling `a()`?

Comment: The output seems to be the equivalent of ```window``` in Node.JS.

Comment: Are you assigning `self` to anything else in those async functions?

Comment: @Andy No, the code is as-is.

Comment: [`module.exports`](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) expects a "real" object, but you're providing a function. To me your posted code would end up with `test has no method b` first. Is this your real code (i.e. no parenthesis missing or something)?

Comment: @Passerby I am returning a real object. The return returns ```{ ... functions here ... }``` which is a perfectly valid object.

Comment: @alexandernst No, your posted code is returning a function to `module.exports`. You'll have to execute it (e.g. `require("test.js")();` or `module.exports=(function(){...})();`) to return an object.

Comment: @Passerby Yes, excuse me. I'm running the function returned, which then returns the object. Check my edit

Comment: I've managed to get your code working as you've written it, so something else must be going on.

Comment: @Andy that is weird indeed. Let me re-check my code and edit if something is different than mine.

Comment: Not sure. I've tried to implement something similar using a function and the only thing I can suggest is: `imap_notify.on_new_mail(my_code[my_func]());`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the external library probably change the context (calling your function with `.bind(this)`).

You can store your object in one variable and call it directly

```
module.exports = function(vars){

    var obj =  {

        a: function(){
            console.log("a()");
        },

        b: function(){

            // var self = this; // useless now

            async.series([
                function(callback){

                    callback();
                },
                function(callback){

                    callback();
                }
            ], function(){
                obj.a(); // <--- now it works
            });
        }

    };

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the solution :)  Anyways, I'm wondering why my way is failing. (I can't see any binds in the "on_new_mail" func)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, don't know if it is valid though

```
var async = require("async");

var Item = function(){
    self= this;

    self.a= function(){
        console.log("a()");
    },

    self.b= function(){



        async.series([
            function(callback){
                ...
                callback();
            },
            function(callback){
                ...
                callback();
            }
        ], function(){
            self.a(); // <------- err
        });
    }
}



module.exports = function(){

    return new Item();

}
```

Comment: It's not. `this` === `module`.

Comment: Indeed, this is not valid.

Comment: Even if this was valid, it doesn't help the fact that the idea of storing `this` as a local variable is to allow access to it within anonymous functions, where the context is no longer the object.